# racoon-tool doesn't generate full racoon.conf file in /var/lib/racoon/racoon.conf

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ipsec, racoon

I am using ipsec-tools/racoon to create my VPN.  I am using racoon-tool to configure racoon.conf but when I run racoon-tool reload it only generates the first section - Global items.

When I run racoon-tool I get:
# racoon-tool reload
Loading SAD and SPD...
SAD and SPD loaded.
Configuring racoon...done.

This is the entire file /var/lib/racoon/racoon.conf
#
# Racoon configuration for Samuel

# Generated on Wed Jan  5 21:31:49 2011 by racoon-tool
#

#
# Global items
#
path pre_shared_key "/etc/racoon/psk.txt";
path certificate "/etc/racoon/certs";
log debug;

I cannot find anywhere a solution as to why this is happening.  Please help

Answer (score 1):

racoon-tool is not for creating the configuration, it's for controlling the racoon server/IPSEC from an existing configuration file.  When [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/racoon-tool.8.html) says `racoon-tool reload` will "Regenerate configuration from  /etc/racoon/racoon.conf, HUP racoon(8) and reinitialise the SPD and SAD." it means that it's loading the changes you've made to the configuration file, not that it's creating a new configuration file for you.

As for a utility to help you create a racoon.conf file... I've got nothing.  [KVpnc](http://home.gna.org/kvpnc/en/index.html) might help but it works as more of a client than a server and may just control racoon directly.

Comment: I think that line you quote is a typo, I think it should read /etc/racoon/racoon-tool.conf.  It also does generate a file in /var/lib/racoon called racoon.conf.  I know this because each time I run racoon-tool reload the file has a new timestamp and the date inside the file changes.  Additionally in the default settings for racoon it is set to use racoon-tool so it knows to look in /var/lib/racoon for its racoon.conf file.  So I still don't understand why its not generating correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Racoon is probably regenerating your conf every time it is restarted and eventually reads it from `/var/lib/racoon/racoon.fr`

To change this behaviour, on Ubuntu, modify your `/etc/default/racoon` to

```
CONFIG_MODE="direct"
```

(rather than `CONFIG_MODE="racoon-tool"` ).

Then, restart racoon.